# The It Hit WebDAV client side module asking for sign in while opening word document

Tags: reactjs, iis, webdav

i am using IIS to configure the WebDAV file accessing .

and using the respective website to browse and open the file.

but it's asking for sign in.

any idea about this.

Comment: Could you login in by manual input user credential? What authentication are you using for your WebDav?basic or windows authentication? If you are trying to access WEBDAV via windows authentication and domain, please remember to register SPN for your authenticated user. Besides, please try to add the website to local intranet so that credential could be passed automatically.

Comment: got it. thanks it's webDAV server issue. have to use .net version of WebDAV server.